# There is no projective covers for $\mathrm{Frac}(D)=K$ over integral domain $D$ which is not a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $D$ be an integral domain which is not a field and $K=\operatorname{Frac}(D)$. I want to prove that $K$ does not have a projective cover as $D$-module. My idea is to use the fact that if a module $M_{R}$ is projective and injective, then $M_{R}=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$. This fact is proved here

[A problem about an $R$-module that is both injective and projective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585495/a-problem-about-an-r-module-that-is-both-injective-and-projective)

Also, it can be proved that $K$ is an injective $D$-module. So I study the particular case of $\mathbb{Q}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ which is not projective. My idea is to prove that if there is a projective cover $\rho:P \to K$, then we must get that $P \cong K$ so that $K$ must be projective and injective, then $K= \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Any help in order finish up this problem?

Comment: How is this different from your previous post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3652180/let-d-be-an-integral-domain-which-is-not-field-and-q-textfracd-then-q)?

Comment: I didnt apply correctly Bass Theorem which states if every flat module $M_{D}$ is projective, every module $M_{D}$ has projective cover. I only  show that the module $K_{D}$ which is flat cannot be projective non zero. But seems like the answer given still helps, so I reformulate the way it can be proven at this question. Still cannot see how to conclude this :/ @KReiser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$

I think you're missing the following lemma:

> Let $M$ be a flat module.  $M$ has a projective cover iff $M$ is projective.

**Remark:** this is a special case of the fact that a projective cover of a module, when it exists, is equivalent to the flat cover of that module (which always exists).

The following can be done in far more generality, cf Wisbauer's *Foundations of Module and Ring Theory*, chapter $7$.  I just wanted to give a short mostly self-contained proof here.

First let me make sure that we're on the same page about

> **Definitions** An exact sequence $\mathcal{C} = 0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ of $R$-modules is called **pure exact** if it satisfies either of the following equivalent conditions: (1) $N \otimes_R \mathcal{C}$ is exact for all $R$-modules $N$ (2) $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M, \mathcal{C})$ is exact for all finitely presented modules $M$.  (See Lam's *Lectures on Modules and Rings*, 4.89 for details).  An $R$-module $M$ is called **pure projective** if for every pure exact sequence $\mathcal{C}$, $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M, \mathcal{C})$ is exact.  (See [Stacks Definition 46.8.1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06ZX) and Wisbauer 33.6 for equivalent conditions, e.g. that pure exact sequences ending in $M$ split).  A submodule $N \subseteq M$ is **superfluous** if for any other submodule $H$ of $M$, $N + H = M \implies H = M$.  A **projective cover** of an $R$-module $M$ is a projective module $P$ together with a surjection $P \rightarrow M$, the kernel of which is a superfluous submodule of $P$.

A couple notes about these definitions.  If $N$ is a superfluous direct summand of $M$, then $N$ is clearly $0$.  A projective module is clearly pure projective, and using characterization (2) of pure exact sequences, it becomes apparent that a finitely presented module is pure projective too. It's easy to see that pure projective modules are closed under direct sums.

> **Lemma**: Let $K$ be a finitely generated submodule of a projective module $P$.  Then $P/K$ is pure projective.

**Proof**: Suffice it to assume that $P$ is free, as the proof generalizes easily.  Note that $M$ is contained in a finite free submodule $F'$ of $F$, and that $F/F' \cong (F/K)/(F'/K)$ is a free module and that $F'/K$ is finitely presented.  Thus $0 \rightarrow F'/K \rightarrow F/K \rightarrow (F/K)/(F'/K) \rightarrow 0$ splits, and hence $F/K$ is a direct sum of a free module and a finitely presented module, so is pure projective.  $\square$

Actually "projective" could have been replaced with "pure projective" in the above, but a little more work would need to be done.  You can refer to [Stacks Lemma 46.8.2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06ZX) or Wisbauer 33.6 for the fact that pure projectives are direct summands of finite sums of finitely presented modules, and then proceed similarly.

> **Lemma:** Let $0 \rightarrow K \rightarrow P \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$ a pure exact sequence where $K$ is a superfluous submodule of $P$ and $P$ is projective.  Then $K = 0$.

**Proof** Let $K'$ be any finite submodule of $K$.
We get a commutative diagram with exact rows as follows:
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> K' @>>> P @>>h'> P/K' @>>> 0 \\
& @VVaV @VV=V @VVcV \\
0 @>>> K @>>> P @>>h> P/K @>>> 0 
\end{CD}

where $c$ is surjective, $a$ is injective.  The previous lemma shows that $P/K'$ is pure projective, so by definition the map $c$ lifts to a map $d$ such that $hd = c$.  Deduce from the superfluousness of $K \subseteq P$ and the surjectivity of $c$ that $d$ is surjective.  Note, using commutativity of the diagram, that the kernel of $dh'$ is a submodule of $K$, and hence is a superfluous submodule of $P$.  The map $dh': P \rightarrow P$ is a surjection onto a projective module, so it splits, i.e. the kernel of $dh'$ is a (superfluous!) direct summand of $P$, so it must be $0$.  Since $K'$ is contained in the kernel of $dh'$, in fact $K'$ is $0$.  But $K'$ was an arbitrary finite submodule of $K$, so we conclude $K = 0$.   $\square$.

> **Main point** If $M$ is flat and has a projective cover $P$, then $M$ is projective.

**Proof:** Suppose that $P$ is a projective cover of a module $M$.  By definition, that means there is an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow K \rightarrow P \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$, where $K$ is a superfluous submodule of $P$.  If $M$ is flat, then this is a pure exact sequence ([Stacks Lemma 10.38.12](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HL)).  By the preceding lemma, $K$ is in fact $0$, and $P \cong M$.  $\square$

From here you can solve your problem in a few different ways.  You want to show that the field of fractions of a non-field domain doesn't have a projective cover.  Equivalently, according to the above, you want to show that the field of fractions is never projective.

Method (1) You know that modules can't be both injective and projective, and you know that the field of fractions is injective.

Method (2) Observe that if an extension of rings $R \subseteq T$ makes $T$ a projective $R$-module, then $T$ is even faithfully flat.  The key is that $T_\mathfrak{p} \not= 0$ for any prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $R$, and then you can argue as in the [comments to this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2871379/projective-and-flat-vs-faithfully-flat).  Now another feature of the field of fractions is that, being a localization, it is an epimorphism in the category of commutative rings.  A faithfully flat epimorphism is always an isomorphism ([Stacks Lemma 10.106.7](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VU)).

As a corollary to Method (2) we can state:

> Let $R \subsetneq T$ be a flat epimorphic extension of rings.  Then $T$ does not have a projective cover.  In particular this holds for any $T = S^{-1}R$ where $S$ is a multiplicative set generated by non-zerodivisors of $R$.

Comment: Thanks @BadamBaplam ! This was ultra hepful, you exactly pointed the piece of the puzzle that I was missing and explained so well! Just wondering what is exactly which is the number of the proposition at Wisbauer´s book where this fact about projective covers fo flat modules mentioned?

Comment: @Cos You're welcome, glad it was helpful! The material I drew from is scattered throughout sections 33-36 of Chapter 7.  The main statement in the exposition I gave corresponds to Wisbauer's 36.4(1).

Comment: Think I came with another proof of the main statement.  The main statement can be: If M has projective cover, M is proyective ifff M is flat. Of course if M is proyective then M is flat. So suppose M is flat, and every module has a flat cover lets say $\rho:F \to M$ but as $M$ is flat then $M \cong F$ right?. So by general hypothesis $M$ has a proyective cover module lets say $P$ and when a module has projective cover it coincides with the flat cover so $P \cong F \cong M$. Then $M$ is projective. Is this line of thought right? @Badam Baplan

Comment: @cos I don't think so. Your reasoning appears circular. You said: "when a module has a projective cover it coincides with the flat cover." True, but that's a stronger result than what you're supposedly proving here. Once you know that flat modules with projective covers are projective, it's easy to prove the coincidence of flat and projective covers.

Comment: Thanks! So you are saying that my line of thought is O.K but im using stronger affirmations that may assume  what im originally supposed to prove right? @Badam Baplan

Comment: @cos right. I'm saying that wasnt a 'proof' in any meaningful sense of the word proof. The line of thought seems ok in that everything you said was true, but (no offense) I don't think it's a very productive line of thought.